# Show that the following two system are a system of alternatives when $x$ is a local minimum

Tags: convex-analysis, systems-of-equations

So as the title suggests I have systems:

**System 1** (a convex function $f$):

$$\langle \nabla f(x^*), d \rangle < 0$$

**System 2** (all $g_i$'s are convex functions):

$$g_i(x^*) + \langle \nabla g_i(x^*), d \rangle < 0 \quad \quad \forall i\in[m]$$

$$g_i(x^*) \leq 0$$

I have to show that no such $d$ exists which will solve both the systems if $x^*$ is a local minimum? I hve tried a lot but could not solve. Any hint would be appreciated. Refere to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EafEv1SYmwE&list=PLbMVogVj5nJQHFqfiSdgaLCCWvDcm1W4l&index=6) (6:50)